# View item list ranking

Tags: views

I have a view with a list of nodes of a certain type sorted by a custom field.

Is there any way to put a ranking number on the output of a view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Assume you just want a row counter (1, 2, 3…). Just add the field "Global: View result counter".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, in `Format` of your View settings, select `HTML list`. and in the settings of this `HTML list` select `Ordered list`

Comment: This option could be useful, but since I'm using pagination, the counter is resets with every update. Your solution is good but @uwe999's is better. +1 for you! Thanks!